# Multiple URL from list used in CURL

Tags: php, list, curl, dom

I have created this script:

```
<?php
    
            
        </head>
    
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <fieldset>
    
    
    <legend>Linki</legend>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textarea">Linki</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">                     
        <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="name">kazdy link w osobnej linijce </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="wyslij"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="wyslij" name="wyslij" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    
    
    
    
    
    <table>
    <?
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$lista[$i]."</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </html>
```

and it's not working as i was expecting.

when i enter urls into form it cut it with explode and every url set as new list element.

For example urls:

```
google.com 
yahoo.com 
ebay.com
```

creates

```
lista[0] -> google.com 
lista[1] -> yahoo.com 
lista[2] -> ebay.com
```

and now i would like to use every single url from list in `$html = "file_get_contents_curl($lista[$i]);"` to scrape `og:image`

but it doesnt work.
When i use only one url in form, then it creates as result url to `og:image` from listened url. When in form are multiple urls, then as results it display only urls from form.

**For example how it should work:**

url in form:

```
https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-HP-Stream-14-Laptop-Celeron-N3060-4GB-RAM-32GB-32-GB-eMMC-Windows-10/292593246536?_trkparms=5373%3A5000006400%7C5374%3ATech%7C5079%3A5000006400
```

return:

```
https://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/292593246536-0-1/s-l1000.jpg
```

---

urls in form:

```
https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-HP-Stream-14-Laptop-Celeron-N3060-4GB-RAM-32GB-32-GB-eMMC-Windows-10/292593246536?_trkparms=5373%3A5000006400%7C5374%3ATech%7C5079%3A5000006400
https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-HP-Stream-14-Laptop-Celeron-N3060-4GB-RAM-32GB-32-GB-eMMC-Windows-10/292593246536?_trkparms=5373%3A5000006400%7C5374%3ATech%7C5079%3A5000006400
```

**should return:**

```
https://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/292593246536-0-1/s-l1000.jpg
https://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/292593246536-0-1/s-l1000.jpg
```

*but instead it returns:*

```
https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-HP-Stream-14-Laptop-Celeron-N3060-4GB-RAM-32GB-32-GB-eMMC-Windows-10/292593246536?_trkparms=5373%3A5000006400%7C5374%3ATech%7C5079%3A5000006400
https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-HP-Stream-14-Laptop-Celeron-N3060-4GB-RAM-32GB-32-GB-eMMC-Windows-10/292593246536?_trkparms=5373%3A5000006400%7C5374%3ATech%7C5079%3A5000006400
```

How to change that. Im newbie in php and created this code in few hours from others scripts found on the internet.

Comment: Don't expect that it'll fix your problem, but it should be `for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)` (not `$i<=$count`). If there are 3 URLs, they will have indices 0, 1, 2, so your loop needs to stop before you get to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)` should be `for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)`, `curl_close($ch);` should be called in `file_get_contents_curl`. Have you confirm that `og:image` exists in every that three websites?

Comment: Yes, even on url multipled returns only url.
For example:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Dyson-Supersonic-Hair-Dryer-Refurbished/273605974730?_trkparms=pageci%3Abbafd652-13a7-11e9-b692-74dbd180c10d%7Cparentrq%3A3011696d1680ab674b77bf43fffcf054%7Ciid%3A1

return:

https://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/273605974730-0-1/s-l1000.jpg

but few same link return only links.

Comment: Try to replace `file_get_contents_curl($lista[$i]); ` to `file_get_contents_curl(trim($lista[$i])); `, to remove `\n` from url, or it will cause curl eror `Illegal characters found in URL`,  I've tried, it works.